# Asp.Net MVC this site can't be reached error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I can't run default asp.net mvc application from visual studio 2019. When i run it, it opens the browser and shows me:

> This site can’t be reached
> The connection was reset.
> Try:

> - Checking the connection
> - Checking the proxy and the firewall
> - Running Windows Network Diagnostics

Error: `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

I tried all kinds of methods.

- Deleting application config file from .vs folder, it didn't work
- Copy/Pasting localhost certificate into Trusted Root Certification Authorities folder in mmc.exe;
- restarting computer.

Nothing yet worked. I'm stuck on this problem for whole day...

Comment: Did visual studio stop when the connection was reset or was it still in debug mode?

Comment: @Tavershima it was in debug mode, and visual studio didn't stopped